# HTML Report in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, html-reports-jenkins

I would like to create html report in Jenkins in the main page of the project but but the path I'm setting that's supposed to point to where the report is, Jenkins tells me it doesn't exist.

Could someone please tell me exactly how to write it down?

The path that i write is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job/app-offerhop/job/job/applications/job/e2e_test/ws/e2e/report/output/report/
```

And the message that appears when it finishs the execution is :

```
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job/app-offerhop-job/job/applications/job/e2e_test/ws/e2e/report/output/report to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/app-offerhop-job/jobs/applications/jobs/e2e_test/htmlreports/HTML_Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/job/app-offerhop-job/job/applications/job/e2e_test/ws/e2e/report/output/report' does not exist.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Finished: FAILURE
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**htmlpublisher** use relative path to the job workspace.
You can check the path of the html by using Jenkins workspace explorer.

As example, in one of my project, I can access to my html file with jenkins workspace explorer at this address:
http://jenkins.org.com:8080/job/Project1/job/Branch_BL1/29/execution/node/3/ws/Work/Exe/MyReport.html

I remove everything before `/ws/`, the path to the html is `Work/Exe/MyReport.html`